# Magento : Add Coupon Code at sales order grid

Tags: magento-1.7

I want to add coupon code in sales order grid . As we know Sales order gird build from sales_flat_order_grid table

Coupon_code column is exist in sales_flat_order table not sales_flat_order_grid table.

When  I add  coupon_code at sales order grid but when i search the coupon code with status column then got this **error :** Column 'status' in where clause is ambiguous

**Note :** I am working on existing project not new project

**Magento version :** 1.7.02
Can you please provid me solution

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `filter_index` to your `addColumn` method to specify which table you want to search for `status`.

I assume the problem is that `status` exists in both `sales_flat_order_grid` and `sales_flat_order`.

There are loads of links on this around the place. Try [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17132/add-a-filtering-column-in-admin-grid) or [here](http://www.adrianbadowski.pl/2013/06/01/filter-index/) amongst others.